# Module not found when trying to lazy load component file in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to implement a way to display components on demand by means of dynamic components and lazy load.

However when it comes to dynamically importing the component file, I get this error:

> Error: **Cannot find module** '@/components/pages/UsersPage.vue'
> at eval (eval at ./src/components/multiwindows lazy recursive

This is the component called Multiwindows (a cut short version), in which I try to load the selected component:

```
<template>
   <component :is="getComponent()"></component>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
     props: ['window'],
     methods: {
        getComponent(window) {
            const path = `@/components/pages/${this.window.component}.vue`;
            return import(path);
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**window** is an object passed as a prop including the data needed for the selected component. An example of it would be (note the **component** property which is the one taking place in the code above):

```
{
   name: 'Users',
   class: 'far fa-user',
   component: 'UsersPage',
}
```

The file structure of my project is like this:

- **src**

  - **components**

    - **multiwindows**

      - MultiWindows.vue
    - **pages**

      - UsersPage.vue

I can't get to asynchronously import **UsersPage.vue**, and it doesn't matter if I change the path constant to a relative path, which since I'm importing from MultiWindows, should be like this:

```
const path = `../pages/${window.component}.vue`;
```

or if I try with an absolute path, both starting with / or not:

```
const path = `/src/components/pages/${window.component}.vue`;
```

EDIT:

I also noticed these errors in console:

> sockjs.js?9be2:1687 WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://mydomain/sockjs-node/919/1qzk04x2/websocket' failed:

> sockjs.bundle.js:1 Uncaught Error: Incompatible SockJS! Main site
> uses: "1.5.2", the iframe: "1.5.0".

Chances are these errors are related to the module not being imported, but I don't know how to fix them. I explicitly installed the sockjs-client package with NPM in case it was due to an outdated version. No success.

**EDIT 2:**

Adapting my code to what @jeremy-castelli suggested:

```
async getComponent(window) {
      const path = `@/components/pages/${this.window.component}.vue`;
      return await defineAsyncComponent(() => import(path));
}
```

I got no error now, but instead I get this warning, and the component is still not displayed:

> Component is missing template or render function.

The loaded component has all the elements: template, script, etc. I checked **defineAsyncComponent** returns an **AsyncComponentWrapper**, which is in turn assigned to the *:is* attribute of the  component

Comment: webpack or vite?

Comment: Using Vue CLI with Webpack

Answer (score 1):

I tested a solution for using dynamic component and lazy load them in Vue-js version **2**. I'm not sure that it works for version **3**. I used **computed properties** instead of Vue methods. Here is my index page code that passes the data to **containerCompo** component (the corresponding Multiwindows component in the question):

```html
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <v-container
      class="px-0"
      fluid
    >

      <v-row>
        <v-col md="12">
          <container-compo :window1="compoData">
          </container-compo>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import containerCompo from "../components/containerCompo";
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      compoData: {
        name: 'Users',
        class: 'far fa-user',
        component1: 'dynamic1', // the name of dynamic component
      }
    }
  },
  components: {
    containerCompo,
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

the containerCompo has "window1" prop that accepts the data include the component name. Here is the code of **containerCompo** component:

```html
<template>
<section>
    <component v-if="isCompoVisible" :is="getComponent"></component>
    <v-btn @click="isCompoVisible= true">click me</v-btn>
</section>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'containerCompo',
    data () {
        return {
            isCompoVisible: false,
        }
    },
    props: ["window1"],
    computed: {
        getComponent() {
            let data = this.window1.component1;
            return () => import(`./${data}`);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The **getComponent** computed data processes the **window1** prop and extract the dynamic component name to be used in vue `<component>` tag. I supposed that `containerCompo.vue` and all dynamic components are in the same level in **components** folder of Vue and **index.vue** is in the **views** folder.

Comment: There's an error if I try to run your snippet. Anyway, that's more or less what I tried to do, isn't it?

Comment: @luis.ap.uyen what was the error? it does not show me error in my local development. and about your statement, yes that is similar to your method but I tried to remove the error of ```Cannot find module```  by using **computed properties** instead of "Vue methods".

Comment: The problem is: I'm showing a code cut short. In reality, I need to use methods instead of computed properties, because <component> is looped, for each open window, and I must pass the corresponding component name through `<component :is="getComponent(window.component)">` since **window** actually comes from a prop called **windows**, which is an array containing each **window** object. I shortened it with a view to make it clear and come to the point.

Comment: Moreover, shouldn't I use defineAsyncComponent() in Vue3 as suggested in another answer?

Comment: I’m not sure about what you want to do, but as I know you can loop through **windows object or array** in a computed property also and then choose the window you want and set it as **data variable** in my answer to load the correct component. And about ```defineAsyncComponent``` I don’t know a lot about that feature of ```Vue3.js```.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the complete solution but it may help you

You need to register a component before using it
and there is also a method to dynamically import components `defineAsyncComponent`

```
import app from '@/main';
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
....
 // Check if the component has already been registered.
 if (!app._context.components[componentName]) {
    app.component(
        componentName,
        defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`@/components/pages/${componentName}.vue`)),
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and while the error has been fixed, I still get a warning and the component is not displayed yet. I have edited the question (EDIT 2) with the details based on your suggestion.

Comment: in the code you added you don't seem to register the component

Comment: how can I register a component whose name isn't known until its imported? If I were to manually register each and every component which will be imported, I should import all of them explicitly too, without lazy load. Otherwise I would get an error saying the registered component was not imported.

Comment: read again my code snippet, dynamic registration is handled. And please don't forget I'm trying to help you, I don't like the tone of your comment

Comment: I'm quite surprised, since I didn't mean to sound rude or in a bad tone whatsoever. Maybe I don't know to express myself in a better way in English. My apologies for that.

Comment: ok mate no worries, so did you managed to do it ? 
In your code you try to assign to <component> the imported file, actually you should only assign the component name of the dynamically created/registered component (the app.component() method)

Comment: I get your point in your solution. However I ended up using Vue Router instead of dynamic components. In that case, lazy loading components didn't cause me any problem. Thanks anyway. Your code was clarifying anyway.

Comment: ok cool, glad you found a solution